# Is it correct and natural to say "my tablet is an average price" meaning when it comes to price, it's average?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say my *tablet is an average price* meaning when it comes to price, it's average? For example:

> Even though my tablet is **an average price**, it fulfills my needs.

If it's not natural, would it be more correct to say my tablet is *average in price*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My tablet is an average price" is understandable, but sounds a little stilted and non-fluent, partly because it sounds like you're saying your tablet *is* a price, rather than having one.  Also, *average* is a little unusual in this context.

It would be more idiomatic and fluent to say

> Even though my tablet is **only a mid-priced one**

([Examples of "is a mid-priced X" usage.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is%20a%20mid-priced%22))

or maybe

> Even though my tablet is **of modest price**

([example](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ottoman_Egypt_and_the_Emergence_of_the_M/4gPVBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22of%20modest%20price%22))

or

> Even though my tablet is **of moderate price**

([example](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Product_Design/qYO1DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22of%20moderate%20price%22))